# Wait for certain word in teraterm

Tags: scripting, macros, teraterm

I am now doing some teraterm script which I want to wait for certain word (in some large string) and if the word is found then execute a command, if not found execute another command. I tried to use wait and if_else, but it's not working, please help.

Comment: how do you send something with tera term and wait for a certain response. It is somewhat frustrating to go through the documentation of tera term and to figure out after a long search that this basic use of tera term, well, is not exactly explained anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your question, I believe that you can achieve the right solution without the use of **if_else**. I just involved myself in scripting in teraterm a week ago, my experience and knowledge so far is in the COM Port communication. For example, I will show a code snippet to login:

```
;Set the COM port
connect '/C=5'

;Set Baud rate
setbaud 9600

;Set the display
showtt 1

;Set the timeout in seconds and result
timeout = 10
result = 1

;Set the username and password's prompt and value
UsernamePrompt='login:'
PasswordPrompt='Password:'
Username='admin'
Password='mypasword'

;Wait for the UsernamePrompt
wait UsernamePrompt
;If timeout occurs, result will be 0, else, result will be 1
if result = 0 goto Error
if result = 1 goto Ok

:Error
;Do the processing here if timeout occurs

:Ok
;Do the processing here if UsernamePrompt is received
sendln Username
```

I believe that this will help you. You may go here:https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/macro/command/wait.html
to learn about **timeout** and  **wait**

Have a nice day.

Hari

Answer (score 1):

As with my experiment, I found out that waitln is still usable when dealing with large string. I use waitln to wait for a string long enough(more then two words) and use if...then...endif.

Answer (score 0):

check timeout period of the macro. explicitly provide some value of timeout